# how to insert date in mysql database from php mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, date, insert

i am doing is that i take current date and one increment date to 1 day 
the format i used for date works when inserting directly into the mysql. but from php it is showing this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'issuedate='2019/11/18' returndate='2019/11/19' WHERE id='2'' at line 1

```
    $date1=date('Y/m/d');
                        $date2=strftime("%Y/%m/%d", strtotime("$date1 +1 day"));
                        //$date2=strtotime();
                        //$date=date('y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'strtotime($date1)));
                         echo "$date1";
                         echo "$date2";


                    echo "<tbody><tr style='background-color:#64626f; color:white;'><td>".$row['bookid']."</td><td>".$row['userid']."</td><td><form method='post'>".$date1."</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td>".$date2."</td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td><input type='submit' value='CONFIRM ISSUE' class=''  name='issuec' /></form></td></tr></tbody></table>";

                    echo "<br/>";
                    if(isset($_POST['issuec'])){

                    $sqli="UPDATE issue SET status='1' issuedate='$date1' returndate='$date2' WHERE id='$id'";
                    $result2=mysqli_query($con,$sqli)or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439

Comment: what prepared statement

Comment: Put , comma after status =1 , and after issuedate too

Comment: seriously dont have time todo all these changings just plz tell me which format of date should enter. i have to submit my project

Comment: Side note: `<form>` cannot be made a child of `<table>`.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: thanks for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in a comment, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. If possible I would recommend switching to PDO and/or using prepared statements if the option is available.

Considering your fields are set to accept a `date` or `varchar` field type, i would try adding comma separators between your update variables:

`$sqli="UPDATE issue SET status='1', issuedate='$date1', returndate='$date2' WHERE id='$id'";`

Comment: well this works to actually remove that error but now it is showing error

Comment: Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause

Comment: however $id has value issueid if you see in my code

Comment: I would then check that 1. The ID that you've set actually exists in your database, 2. That you're actually setting the value of ````$id````, and 3. Print out your query string ````print($sqli) exit;```` to make sure you're not adding any additional quotation marks.

Comment: Please update my post as the answer to your original question. And please do not downvote answers because they may expose other issues in your code. This answer solved the original error you had posted and answered your question. Thank you and good luck with your project.